# setting nan value when interpolating in scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I want to interpolate a list of values (a pandas' series) using scipy.interpolate.interp1d setting a constant value when the input is a NAN.

The reason for this is that I need to multiply another series for the output of the interpolation, and I would like to multiply by 1 is the input is NAN

Right now i did

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

X = [0,180,360]
Y = [1,10,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[0,180, np.nan, 270, 999]})
interp=  interp1d(X, Y, kind='linear', bounds_error= False)
K = interp(df['b'])
K[[np.isnan(K)]] = 1
df['a'] = df['a'] * K

In [15]: df.a
Out[15]: 
0     1.0
1    20.0
2     3
3    22.0
4     5.0
```

However, since df is rather large, I was looking for something a bit more direct that didn't require the creation of the variable K and to check with np.isnan the vector. Moreover this produce also annoying warnings during interp1d.

For points outside of interpolating boundaries I can do

```
interp=  interp1d(X, Y, kind='linear', bounds_error= False, fill_value = 1)
```

that would allow me to do

```
df['a'] = df['a'] * interp(df['b'])
```

but sadly this does not handles "nan" in df['b'].

Is there a better way to achieve this result?